# how to loop an array and get only the value of a particular index

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a dynamic table where i want only 3 values from my json to display and make one a link which when clicked on, the rest displays. Below is my code kindly assist please.

```
var myInvestment =[
    {
      "investmentNo":"00032",
      "amount":"70000",
      "status": "Expired",
      "repayAmt":"70500",
      "description": "Official",
      "maturityDate":"2020-10-31"
  },

{
     "investmentNo":"00034",
     "amount":"5000",
     "status": "Current",
     "repayAmt":"6000",
     "description": "School fees",
     "maturityDate":"2022-03-31"
 }
] 

var investmentTable = document.querySelector("#investmentTable");
        if(myInvestment.length>0){
var col = []; // define an empty array
            for (var i = 0; i < myInvestment.length; i++) {
                for (var key in myInvestment[i]) {
                    if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                        col.push(key);
                    }
                }
            }   

            // CREATE TABLE HEAD .
            var tHead = document.createElement("tHead");                              
            // CREATE ROW FOR TABLE HEAD .
            var hRow = document.createElement("tr");                     
            // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.            
            tHead.appendChild(hRow);
            investmentTable.appendChild(tHead);            
            // CREATE TABLE BODY .
            var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");                
            // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.
            for (var i = 0; i < myInvestment.length; i++) {            
                    var bRow = document.createElement("tr"); 
                    // CREATE ROW FOR EACH RECORD .
                        var td = document.createElement("td");
                        td.innerHTML = i+1;
                        bRow.appendChild(td);                    

                    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        var td = document.createElement("td");
                        if (j==0) {
                            td.innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick = "return invModalView('+i+')">'+myInvestment[i][col[j]]+ '</a>';
                          bRow.appendChild(td);
                        }else{
                        td.innerHTML = myInvestment[i][col[j]];
                        bRow.appendChild(td);
                         }if (j==2) {
                        td.innerHTML = '<div class="badge">'+myInvestment[i][col[j]]+ '</div>';
                        if (td.textContent=="Current") {
                            td.innerHTML = '<div class="badge badge-success">'+myInvestment[i][col[j]]+ '</div>';
                        } else {
                                  td.innerHTML = '<div class="badge badge-danger">'+myInvestment[i][col[j]]+ '</div>';
                            }

                        }
                    tBody.appendChild(bRow) 
                    }
            investmentTable.appendChild(tBody);   
            }
}
```

**This is my modal function that will display the second table**

```
function invModalView(k,myInvestment){
        var modal = document.getElementById("modal-block-normal");
        modal.style.display = "block";
        var investNo = document.getElementById("investNo");
        var investmentTableModal = document.querySelector("#investmentTableModal");  

        myInvestment
  .forEach((item, i) => {

    var row = investmentTable.insertRow();

    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = item.repayAmt;
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = item.description;
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = item.maturityDate;
  });
}                            
}

HTML
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-vcenter  table-responsive" id="investmentTableModal">

                                <thead id="invtableHead">
                                    <tr >

                                        <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 30%;">Repayment Amount</th>
                                        <td id="repayAmt"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 30%;">Description</th>
                                        <td id="description"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="d-sm-table-cell" style="width: 30%;">Maturity Date</th>
<td id = "matureDate"></td>
                                    </tr>
</table>
```

i want when a user clicks on myInvestment.investmentNo[0], only the repaymentamt, description and maturityDate of myInvestment[0] will show

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of spaghetti code to go through, so I'm not even going to try.

In jQuery, what people normally do is they iterate over the array and construct each button, and then place each button on the dom. Then, they apply a `$.click()` on that button, and inside the `.click` callback they can create a clojure over the original item they created a button for.

like this: https://jsfiddle.net/0d8aL9xr/

```
var items = [{title: 'a bouncing ball', id: 1}, {title: 'a rubber duck', id: 2}];

items.forEach(item => {
  const $newButton = $(`<button>${item.title}</button>`);
  $('.buttons').append($newButton);
  $newButton.click(function() {
    $('#item-id').val(item.id);
    $('#item-name').val(item.title);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function setSession(key,value){
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}

function getSession(key){
    return window.localStorage.getItem(key)
;
}

function unsetSession(key){
    window.localStorage.removeItem(key)
;
}
////// Investment page scripts //////
function investmentData(){

      var InvData = getSession("InvData");
      var myInvestment = JSON.parse(InvData);
var investmentTable = document.querySelector("#investmentTable");
        if(myInvestment.investments.length>0){
var col = []; // define an empty array
            for (var i = 0; i < myInvestment.investments.length; i++) {
                for (var key in myInvestment.investments[i]) {
                    if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                        col.push(key);
                    }
                }
            }   

            // CREATE TABLE HEAD .
            var tHead = document.querySelector("#tableHead");                              
            // CREATE ROW FOR TABLE HEAD .
            var hRow = document.querySelector("#tableRow");                     
            // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.            
            tHead.appendChild(hRow);
            investmentTable.appendChild(tHead);            
            // CREATE TABLE BODY .
            var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");                
            // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.
            for (var i = 0; i < myInvestment.investments.length; i++) {            
                    var bRow = document.createElement("tr"); 
                    // CREATE ROW FOR EACH RECORD .
                        var td = document.createElement("td");
                        td.innerHTML = i+1;
                        bRow.appendChild(td);                    

                    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        var td = document.createElement("td");
                        if (j==0) {
                          td.innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick = "return invModalView('+i+')">'+myInvestment.investments[i][col[j]]+ '</a>';
                          bRow.appendChild(td);
                        }else{
                        td.innerHTML = myInvestment.investments[i][col[j]];
                        bRow.appendChild(td);
                       }if (j==2) {
                      td.innerHTML = '<div class="badge">'+myInvestment.investments[i][col[j]]+ '</div>';
                      if (td.textContent=="Current") {
                        td.innerHTML = '<div class="badge badge-success">'+myInvestment.investments[i][col[j]]+ '</div>';
                      } else {
                  td.innerHTML = '<div class="badge badge-danger">'+myInvestment.investments[i][col[j]]+ '</div>';
              }

                      }
                    tBody.appendChild(bRow) 
                }
            investmentTable.appendChild(tBody);   
      }
}
}



function invModalView(k){
     $('#investmentTableModal').empty();
        var myInv = JSON.parse(getSession("InvData"));  
        var modal = document.getElementById("modal-block-normal");
        modal.style.display = "block";
        var investmentTableModal = document.querySelector("#investmentTableModal");                              
            // CREATE TABLE BODY .
            var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");

            // // ADD COLUMN HEADER TO ROW OF TABLE HEAD.

            // // Investment No
              var bRow = document.createElement("tr"); 
              var th = document.createElement("th");                        
              th.innerHTML = "Investment No";
              var td2 = document.createElement("td");
              td2.style.width = "30%"; 
              th.style.width = "30%";                     
              td2.innerHTML = myInv.investments[k].investmentNo;
                        bRow.appendChild(th);    
                        bRow.appendChild(td2);                  
              tBody.appendChild(bRow);
              investmentTableModal.appendChild(tBody)


            // Investment duration
            var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");   
                  var bRow = document.createElement("tr"); 
              var th = document.createElement("th");                        
              th.innerHTML = "Duration";
              var td2 = document.createElement("td");                        
              td2.innerHTML = myInv.investments[k].duration;
                        bRow.appendChild(th);    
                        bRow.appendChild(td2);                  
              tBody.appendChild(bRow) 
              investmentTableModal.appendChild(tBody); 


              // investment start date
            var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");   
                  var bRow = document.createElement("tr"); 
              var th = document.createElement("th");                        
              th.innerHTML = "startDate";
              var td2 = document.createElement("td");                        
              td2.innerHTML = myInv.investments[k].startDate;
                        bRow.appendChild(th);    
                        bRow.appendChild(td2);                  
              tBody.appendChild(bRow) 
              investmentTableModal.appendChild(tBody);


              // investment yield
            var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");   
                  var bRow = document.createElement("tr"); 
              var th = document.createElement("th");                        
              th.innerHTML = "Yield";
              var td2 = document.createElement("td");                        
              td2.innerHTML = myInv.investments[k].yield;
                        bRow.appendChild(th);    
                        bRow.appendChild(td2);                  
              tBody.appendChild(bRow) 
              investmentTableModal.appendChild(tBody);


              // investment repayment Amount
            var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");   
                  var bRow = document.createElement("tr"); 
              var th = document.createElement("th");                        
              th.innerHTML = "Repayment Amount";
              var td2 = document.createElement("td");                        
              td2.innerHTML = myInv.investments[k].repayAmt;
                        bRow.appendChild(th);    
                        bRow.appendChild(td2);                  
              tBody.appendChild(bRow) 
              investmentTableModal.appendChild(tBody);


              // investment description
            var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");   
                  var bRow = document.createElement("tr"); 
              var th = document.createElement("th");                        
              th.innerHTML = "Description";
              var td2 = document.createElement("td");                        
              td2.innerHTML = myInv.investments[k].description;
                        bRow.appendChild(th);    
                        bRow.appendChild(td2);                  
              tBody.appendChild(bRow) 
              investmentTableModal.appendChild(tBody);


              // investment maturityDate
            var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");   
                  var bRow = document.createElement("tr"); 
              var th = document.createElement("th");                        
              th.innerHTML = "MaturityDate";
              var td2 = document.createElement("td");                        
              td2.innerHTML = myInv.investments[k].maturityDate;
                        bRow.appendChild(th);    
                        bRow.appendChild(td2);                  
              tBody.appendChild(bRow) 
              investmentTableModal.appendChild(tBody);


}


////// Create Localstorage for MyInvestment ////
var myInvestment =  '{"investments":[{"investmentNo":"00032","amount":"70000","status": "Expired","duration": "2","startDate": "2020-02-02","yield": "2.60","repayAmt":"70500","description": "Official","maturityDate":"2020-10-31"},{"investmentNo":"00033","amount":"40000","status": "Current","duration": "3","startDate": "2019-01-05","yield": "12.0","repayAmt":"42000","description": "Personal","maturityDate":"2020-12-31"},{"investmentNo":"00034","amount":"5000","status": "Current","duration": "4","startDate": "5-04-2008","yield": "20.0","repayAmt":"6000","description": "School fees","maturityDate":"2022-03-31"}]}'

setSession("InvData",myInvestment);
```

I later succeeded in getting this. i think it would be nice to share for someone out there who might need it.